# frame hook load theme causes frame to crash after creation

Tags: hooks, frames, themes, emacs-daemon

I have attempted to change my emacs theme. I am using the emacs daemon and I have attempted to create a hook to change the theme on frame creation. However when this hook is active the frame crashes immediately upon activation without an error message

This is the chunk from my init.el

```
(defun my-change-emacs-theme ()
  "theme is a symbol as accepted by load-theme"
  (load-theme 'whiteboard t))
(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions 'my-change-emacs-theme )
```

Comment: Depending on circumstances, you might prefer `(unless (memq 'whiteboard custom-enabled-themes) (load-theme 'whiteboard t))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `after-make-frame-functions`.

You've given it a function which takes NO arguments, but which is going to be *called* with one.  So that's going to cause an error.

Any time you use `add-hook` with a hook variable which *doesn't* end in `-hook` you know you need to check the documentation:

> If the hook variable’s name does not end with ‘-hook’, that indicates
> it is probably an “abnormal hook”.  These differ from normal hooks in
> two ways: they can be called with one or more arguments, and their
> return values can be used in some way.  The hook’s documentation says
> how the functions are called and how their return values are used.  Any
> functions added to an abnormal hook must follow the hook’s calling
> convention.  By convention, abnormal hook names end in ‘-functions’.

-- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Hooks`

Comment: p.s. The approach to using this particular hook which is demonstrated in https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/47455/454 might also be useful to you.